# How to add custom subclass in cocoa framework

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift4, ios-library

I have just started making a custom library for reusing.
I have multiple files which I want to put in that reusable file and am able to do that.
But the problem is that I while importing all files are getting imported,
I am want to import specific .swift file.

How can I implement that?[image]

Example:
I want to add multiple .swift in CocoaLibrary folder.
and when import CoCoaLibrary, I want to do import like

```
import CocoaLibrary.CommonConstant
```

I don't know the path to implement this, so just mentioning the desired result.